# Mysql Query Performance (difference between 2 queries)

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE f1 >= 'a' ORDER BY f1 LIMIT 100;

SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE f1 ='a' OR f1 > 'a' ORDER BY f1 LIMIT 100;
```

The first query runs really fast, the second doesn't even return at all.

table1 has composite primary key
(f1,key2,key3,key4)

Any idea why?

Comment: second has no ;

Comment: This happens because of arithmetic evaluations. '>=' is a single arithmetic operation.

Comment: Because MySQL is simply unable to determine that both where clauses are identical.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL has to make look for two conditions is second query. It first's satisfies first and move on to the other. While in the first query `>=` is treated as single arithmetic evaluation which will definitely cost's less as compared to second one.

Comment: But, explain query in both the cases gives exactly the same response

Comment: Because both queries have exactly same condition.

Answer (score 0):

You are running exactly the same condition using different arithmetic implementations.

**First one**

'**>=**' is a single arithmetic operation

**Second one**

**f1 ='a' OR f1 > 'a'**
Now we have multiple arithmetic operations. It should check **f1 ='a'** and **f1 > 'a'**
separately and again want to check the **OR** condition.

So definitely the First query is executing fast.